# Rails 4 call method in validation exclude

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to add a validation to exclude a list of reserved usernames:

```
validates :rss_mailbox, exclusion: { in: %w(admin support info), message: " %{value} is not available" }
```

But the list is extremely long.  Is there a way to call a method for the `in:` property instead of hardcoding a huge list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what the docs for [validates_exclusion_of](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/HelperMethods.html#method-i-validates_exclusion_of) says about `:in`:

> :in - An enumerable object of items that the value shouldn't be part of. This can be supplied as a proc, lambda or symbol which returns an enumerable. If the enumerable is a range the test is performed with

This makes it quit flexible, I think you can also use a class constant:

```
RESERVED = %w(admin support info etc)

validates :rss_mailbox, exclusion: { in: RESERVED, message: " %{value} is not available" }
```

Not tested, but I think you can use a method by referring to it with a symbol:

```
validates :rss_mailbox, exclusion: { in: :reserved_names, message: " %{value} is not available" }

def reserved_names
  # Lookup and return all reserved names, can be array or db-call
end
```

Comment: Thanks the symbol method works great. I wish I understood symbols better.

Comment: Symbols are simply immutable Strings, which means that you cannot change a symbol during its lifetime. This makes them faster than Strings that are mutable; a String that you can change. If you want to  point to a variable or method by its name, you could do something like `get_attr('name')`, but since you never want to change the string `'name'`, you might as well do `get_attr(:name)` since you never want to change `:name` to somthing else. This executes a little faster.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation too.  You're a real champ

Answer (score 0):

You can polish this implementation using a separate custom validator class as show in [this guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#validates-with).

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_with CustomValidator
end

class CustomValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate(record)
    if invalid_condition_implementation(record)
      record.errors[:rss_mailbox] << "My custom error message"
    end
  end
end
```